# Dictionary object accessed by concurrent users in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Asp.Net page i have a static dictionary object where values can be added and retrieved, When 100's of concurrent users access the page is there any chance my dictionary object may get locked / throw error ?

User can 
1) Add new value if it does not exist 
2) Retrieve existing value. They cannot modify / delete

Comment: More importantly than any of this, *why* do you have a "static dictionary object" in ASP.NET? Are you trying to reinvent the cache?

Answer (score 3):

If you use [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) then all access to the Dictionary is threadsafe and the implementation is really performant - most operations are lock-free.

For some explanation and sample source see http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/02/17/c.net-little-wonders-the-concurrentdictionary.aspx

Comment: Thanks, In this case user can 1) Add new value if it does not exist & 2) Retrieve existing value. They cannot modify / delete. Can ordinary dictionary can't handle this situation

Comment: if you only want to allow getting an existing value or alternatively adding new value then use `GetOrAdd` method.

Answer (score 1):

> When 100's of concurrent users access the page is there any chance my dictionary object may get locked / throw error ?

Yes, there's a great chance.

See MSDN's note for `Dictionary(TKey, TValue)` on [thread safety](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.
>
> For a thread-safe alternative, see ConcurrentDictionary.
>
> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe.

Consider using [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks, In this case user can 1) Add new value if it does not exist & 2) Retrieve existing value. They cannot modify / delete. Can ordinary dictionary can't handle this situation

Comment: Adding an element would modify the collection, so there are no thread-safety guarantees for it.